# Excel VBA - Fill down to bottom of sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I've made, but when I run the macro it fills down the updated value to the bottom of the sheet instead of to the bottom of the data set, is there a way to make it only fill down partially?

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    
        With Range("I1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            
                On Error Resume Next
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "1"
                On Error GoTo 0
        End With
   .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: `Range("I1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown))` this is full sheet. Try `Range("I1:I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: Or just simply change `xlDown` to `xlUp`.